# How do I find rows that contain two words "First" + "Second" regardless sequence?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

> #360Search #SearchAll #SearchContain #SearchEverything #SQL #SELECT

How do I find rows that contain two words "First" + "Second" regardless of in sequence or not? looking for a single where condition to cover this case.

Here is MyTable:

```
---------------------------
RowNo, MyStringColumn
---------------------------
1 , 'First Second Third'
2 , 'Second Third First'
3 , 'Third First Second'
4 , 'First Third Second'
5 , 'Second Second Third'
```

Expected Result: Row#1,2,3,4

```
---------------------------
RowNo, MyStringColumn
---------------------------
1 , 'First Second Third'
2 , 'Second Third First'
3 , 'Third First Second'
4 , 'First Third Second'
```

below SQL returns Row#1,3,4 and doesn't return Row#2 due to an unordered sequence.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyStringColumn like '%First%Second%
```

Here is the SQL script to generate MyTable and data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [#MyTable];
SELECT [RowNo],[MyStringColumn] INTO [#MyTable]
FROM (SELECT (1)[RowNo], ('First Second Third')[MyStringColumn]
       UNION SELECT 2, 'Second Third First'
       UNION SELECT 3, 'Third First Second'
       UNION SELECT 4, 'First Third Second'
       UNION SELECT 5, 'Second Second Third'
)t

SELECT * FROM [#MyTable] WHERE [MyStringColumn] LIKE '%First%Second%'
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyStringColumn like '%First%Second% OR MyStringColumn like '%Second%First%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`string_split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) based approach. Useful when you want to check many words:

```
select *
from t
where exists (
    select 1
    from string_split(t.MyStringColumn, ' ')
    where value in ('first', 'second')
    having count(distinct value) = 2 -- this should match the number of items in the "in" clause
)
```

Comment: Thanks, @salman its works!!! as I was looking for it...

Answer (score 2):

Just `LIKE` twice.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyStringColumn LIKE '%First%' 
  AND MyStringColumn LIKE '%Second%'
```

And if you want to make sure it's 2 seperate words

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ' '+MyStringColumn+' ' LIKE '% First %' 
  AND ' '+MyStringColumn+' ' LIKE '% Second %'
```

Comment: But this will also find `twenty-first` and `fifty-second` and `second-last`. Need spaces.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Okay. Those 2 words were probably just for a simplified example. But it could matter.